# Windows 8 Application Packaging

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am working on creating a Windows 8 application.  UI is using HTML5.  Using WinJs I am calling a WCF service that returns a datatable used to build out the UI.  All that is good.

I would also like to create a Window Service that gets packaged up with the application, so when someone download/installs it gets unpackaged and the windows service is started/executed.  Is this type of configuration possible?

The WCF service today is a web service, but I would like to make it a windows service.  The idea is to make everything self contained.  This would allow me to make it available in the Microsoft Online store - if I wanted to go that route.

Comment: Why would you like to run your web service as a windows service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 Applications don't support installing services.  The best you can do is install a service separately.

Comment: Is it possible to include a WCF Windows Service in the Visual Studio solution, create a .bat file and do something with deploying it and calling the .bat to start the service?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.  It would have to be installed entirely separately from the Windows Store installation process.  The Windows Store is for Windows 8 Applications and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Your WCF service should be decoupled from your app and most probably running on a different machine! I am pretty sure that the they are not going to allow you to install or run services in context of a Windows Store App.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a windows service is not an ideal approach for any Windows 8 application. I understand that you want to make everythig self contained but, why as a WCF local service then? Why don't you consider having it has a data access layer in your app itself? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

**REGARDING CLIENT SIDE**

Web services are separate projects and separate deployment models. You can have one Visual Studio project for the Windows 8 client app and one project for the Web Services side.

Windows 8 apps have several options for saving persistent data, such as endpoints for consuming web services.

There are several consideration when storing Windows 8 application data, such as the location of web services to be consumed.

Windows 8 Application data also includes session state, user preferences, and other settings. It is created, read, updated, and deleted when the app is running.

There are **3 types of dimensions** to consider.  The system manages these data stores for your app:
(1) **local**: Persistent data that exists only on the current device 
(2) **roaming**: Data that exists on all devices on which the user has installed the app 
(3) **temporary**: Data that could be removed by the system any time the app isn't running

As a developer, you concern yourself with a couple of objects to persist application data:
The first container object is ApplicationDataContainer. The other is ApplicationData. You can use these objects to store your local, roaming, or temporary data.

**REGARDING SERVER SIDE**

Your Windows 8 Client app will consume http-based web services.

Most developers deploy web services to the cloud to be consumed by iOS, Android, Windows, and other server side services.

Windows Azure is a cloud offering that makes exposing services to clients very simple.

You can leverage either **cloud services** for robust solutions or the lighter weight **Azure Web Sites.**

You can typically choose either of these **two project types** to create web services:

(1) Windows Communication Foundation WCF; or

(2) ASP.NET Web API, which is included with MVC version 4.

**WCF** has been around longer and has historically been the primary choice for developers when it comes to exposing services.

Microsoft's more modern concepts about web services relate to the **ASP.NET Web API,** which truly embracing HTTP concepts (URIs and verbs). Also, the ASP.NET Web API can be used to create services that leverage request/response headers, hypermedia, etc.